# Slider Inaccurate

Tags: ios, iphone, uislider

When I run my app on the simulator, the slider works great, accurate.

However, when the app runs on my phone, the slider is not accurate. For example, my finger points to value 100.0 and at the moment I release my finger from the screen, the value jumps to 102.2 or 98.2 or 91.5. It's never stops on the right value.

Can I fix it? Does anyone faced this problem before?

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simulator allows precise control using a mouse cursor. It doesn't represent reality at all compared to an actual iOS device.

A real iOS device requires the use of your much fatter finger. As you lift your finger you actually touch different parts of the screen. This is typical and not much you can do about it.